# Custom TitleBar in activity ANDROID

Tags: android, tabbar, android-titlebar

I have a problem.
I would like custom my TitleBar and when I try with this method:

**requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mytitle);**

But he crash when i am in the Intent of my TabBar.

He works in my main Activity, I think there are a different method for the intent of tabBar for customize the titleBar.

Someone known how it's done?

I'am a begginer developper Android.

Thanks !

Comment: Plz, paste the logcat output.

Answer (score 0):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);     

getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mytitle);
```

put your setContentLayout(); 
in the middle of these two.